# Creating contact with country code in Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I have some problem when adding a contact to Content Provider with number prefixed with country code, for example "+48515000111". Adding this kind of number causes that my contact have number like "48515000111" so the "+" character is removed.

This is how I add a contact :

```
          ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
          int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

          ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null).build());

          //Phone Number
          ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
              rawContactInsertIndex)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, number)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(Phone.TYPE, "1").build());

          //Display name/Contact name
          ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
              rawContactInsertIndex)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            .build());

        try {
            ctx.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            return "ok";
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error:"+e.getClass().getName()+":"+e.getMessage();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error:"+e.getClass().getName()+":"+e.getMessage();
        }
```

Is there some fix for this ?

Comment: Shouldn't `Phone.TYPE` be an integer like `TYPE_HOME` etc? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html

Comment: Hey @shkschneider, thanks for your help but the problem was somewhere else :) Code pasted above is OK, but the contact info was sent via GCM in JSON format. It seems that putting "+" in JSON string sent via GCM was replaced by white space. I had to URL encode phone number before puting into JSON and now I have my "+" in `number` variable.

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer (yes, answering your own question) to help others and close this (yet open) question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was somewhere else. Code pasted above is OK, but the contact info was sent via GCM in JSON format. It seems that putting "+" in JSON string sent via GCM was replaced by white space. I had to URL-encode phone number before puting into JSON and now I have my "+" in `number` variable.